# Secure web browsing on unencrypted wifi

Tags: network, linux, ssh

Is it possible to securely browse the internet when using unencrypted wifi?

Can I securely connect to a home server and route my traffic through that?

What are the risks with using an `authorized_key` to `ssh` to a home server and tunnel my traffic through it?

Comment: You can use VPN, like OpenVPN. It's safe to use SSH if you watch for key mismatch, SSH should issue warning if the key stored during first connect doesn't match (in .ssh/known_hosts).

Comment: https sites will be safe, others won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to unencrypted wifi opens up the computer you are using to connectivity-based attacks. Open wifi networks can be very hostile.

That said, once connected, using ssh to connect to a host with key exchange can yield a secure channel. Similarly, https connections to known hosts can also yield a secure channel.

However, active watchers on the wifi may decide to take an interest in the target machines. Using one's home router as a proxy may be less wise than just using a disposable cloud instance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an emerging market for secure virtual browsers, which are able to solve this problem by providing a client that connects securely to a browser running remotely in a secure container. Some of the companies in this market are:

- [Authentic8](https://www.authentic8.com/get)
- [Menlo Security](https://www.menlosecurity.com/)
- [Spikes Security](https://spikes.com/index.html)
- [Ntrepid](http://www.ntrepidcorp.com)

Some of these solutions are enterprise focused or require hardware. I prefer Authentic8; but, I'm biased.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a good analysis of how they perform the connectivity between the machine and the secure container?  I find it very curious that, for example, Ntrepid claims to be very secure but does not even implement HTTPS on its website.

Comment: I can only speak to Authentic8's approach. The Authentic8 SILO client talks to the service using TLSv1.2. The TLSv1.2 connection carries traffic for a proprietary protocol for client-server communications and encrypted RDP channels (Just to be clear, the RDP channels are encrypted using methods that are part of RDP, then sent over the TLSv1.2 encrypted connection).